# second css file not loading after refresh

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0

Let me explain my problem with simple example...

example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<ex>True</ex>
```

and my example.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy:compat"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>will get red color from a.css</h1>
        <h2>will get blue color from b.css</h2>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when I open xml file on browser both headlines h1 and h2 comes properly iwth red and blue, 
but after every refresh `<h2></h2>` text comes sometimes in blue and sometimes in black.....
could anyone please let me know the problem?

Comment: Is the missing `"` in the `type="text/xsl` a typo on the question or do you have that in your code aswell?

Comment: just while editin it I forgot closing "..

Comment: The XSLT file must be closed with `/xsl:stylesheet`. Another typo?

Comment: `</xml-stylesheet>` isn't right either. This is just a mess. `xsl:ouput` does not exist of course. Please be careful with the code you post.

Comment: really sorry for the silly mistakes..please answer for the real problem....?

Comment: Apart from the fact that `</xml:stylesheet>` is _still_ wrong (should be **exactly** `</xsl:stylesheet>`), there is no problem with your XLST code. Please show the CSS files as well.

Comment: my css files are :
1. a.css
h1{color:red;}

2. b.css
h2{color:blue;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your XSLT code. And nothing is wrong with your input XML or the CSS files. The only reason I can think of for the behaviour you describe is that `b.css` ceases to be available.

This is the output I get with Firefox, the blue font color stays even if I refresh.

**EDIT**: It might help to have internal CSS styles instead of referencing them from external files.

The stylesheet below does essentially the same as yours, except that the CSS is internal. This might lower the chances of CSS files not being available.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy:compat"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Title</title>
            <style type="text/css">
               h1 {color:red;}
               h2 {color:blue;}
            </style> 
         </head>
         <body>
            <h1>will get red color from a.css</h1>
            <h2>will get blue color from b.css</h2>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: may b problem is with browser's cache. I have a small http server running, for specific request server reads example.xml content and sends to browser with text/xml mime type. for first hit browser gets proper content with blue,red headlines and after refresh the 2nd included css file (here b.css) doesn't shows the blue colored text it's just black colored.

Comment: That could be the reason. Try my edited answer.

Comment: I have lot of css styles so kept in the 2 files and I do use them for other pages also.

Comment: That is beside the point. Your objective should be to find the source of your error. That's why you should try what I suggested.

Comment: I tried with ur solution it just works fine. with my old scenario I need to solve it

Comment: Then I would daresay that your problem has to do with server requests, rather than with XSLT transformations. So, if you decide to ask another question, it is a _bad_ idea to just copy everything into a new question, because it will be deleted as a duplicate. Instead, ask a question about http requests and explain that XSLT is not the problem. Also, if this answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it (mark the tick on the left).